# Regexp_like(), oracle, разбор строк

Tags: oracle, регулярные-выражения, plsql, sql

Добрый день, господа!

Есть таблица:

```
id     value
-------------------------------------------
1      some words xxxxx-xxxx more words
2      awesome words xxxxx-xxxx more words
```

Нужно найти все `awesome words` (регистр и позиция словосочетания произвольная, но порядок всегда железен (может быть AwesOme woRds, например)), в которых отсутствуют числовые подстроки вида `xxxxx-xxxx` (`xxxx-xxxx`, `xxxxx-xxxx`, `xxxxxх-xxxx` (4-6 цифр перед тире 4 всегда после)). Символьные и числовые подстроки могут меняться местами.

Либо у меня что-то не так с SQL Dev, либо я просто нуб...
Для поиска числовых подстрок написал такое (а мне-то, наоборот, выкинуть надо совпадающие подстроки):

```
regexp_like(value, '([\d]{4,6})-([\d]{4})')
```

Вроде ищет, но когда:

```
regexp_like(value, '!([\d]{4,6})-([\d]{4})')
```

Тоже ищет и не выпиливает совпадения... WTF?

Помогите составить грамотное выражение! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так пробовали?

```
select * from tab
where not regexp_like(value, '([\d]{4,6})-([\d]{4})');
```

Comment: Спасибо за NOT!) Регвыр не работал, потому что Oracle не понимал [\d].
Вот таким регвыром решил траблу:

    not regexp_like(purpose, '([0-9]{4,6})-([0-9]{4})')

Answer (score 2):

В python бы прокатило `[^(\d{4,6}-\d{4})]*` с модификатором `g`.

Насчет твоего случая могу сказать только, что надо лезть в дебри sql. Регулярки сами по себе не умеют пропускать или исключать чего-либо из текста. Для этого существуют специальные методы.

---

http://regex101.com/r/oG5yP0/1

Comment: Ну, у меня трудности были именно регуляркой. ) А по словам я проанализировал записи и понял, что там регистр может различаться только в первых символах слов. И в итоге простой like прокатил. )

    like '%_wesome%'

Спасибо!